# I've heard this story to be told in three version

Tags: infinitives

*1. I've heard this story told in three versions.*

*2. I've heard this story to be told in three versions.*

I am not sure whether the second sentence is grammatically OK. If not, can you please explain to me why.

Comment: "I've heard three versions of this story" is probably the most natural way to express this.  Of your examples, #1 is not natural, but still fine.  With #2, "to be told" is not, but I can't say exactly why.  "This story is to be told in three versions" would be ok, though.  I would answer but I'm hoping someone can give a better reason why #2 is wrong.

Comment: The original sentence in version one is _I've heard this story **to have been told** in three versions (_so far_) which is reduced to _told_. However, I don't think the second version is wrong, because it shows this is the common way that this story is told (simple present).

Comment: @Andrew could you please have a look at my understanding of the second sentence? Do you think it's valid? (I would like to seek a native speaker's opinion on that)

Comment: @Yuri it doesn't seem quite right, but again I'm hoping someone with more insight can pinpoint *why*.  "To be told" explains *how*, but doesn't match with "heard".  "I've heard this story *is* to be told in three versions," would be fine, though.

Comment: Oh, thanks, it must be interesting then. I would wait for a good answer to this question +1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The rule](http://www.grammaring.com/see-watch-hear-listen-feel-smell-notice-observe-object-bare-infinitive) is that verbs of perception (see, watch, hear, listen, feel, smell, notice, observe, etc.) are followed by *bare infinitiv*e:

> I heard him tell the story in three versions.

At the same time, *in the passive voice*, a *to-infinitive* is used:

> This story was heard to be told in three versions.

The verbs of perception can also be followed by an object + past participle.

In this structure, the past participle has a passive meaning, and this seems to be your case:

> I heard this story told in three versions.

([the source](http://www.englishgrammar.org/verbs-perception/))

And there's also another alternative to express the idea - *object + verb-ing construction:*

> I heard this story being told in three versions.

Comment: "I heard this story be told in three versions." That's not grammatical. The told should be the bare active infinitve

Comment: **is said to be told** is idiomatic. I don't think you'll find many attestations of "heard to be told".   **Heard told** is well attested.

Comment: @TRomano Yes, "there may be a joke, which is said to be told in various versions by residents of Tijuana, Mexico", but how can one use it in the context "I heard three versions of this story"? Is "was heard to be told" grammatically invalid? The OP's question seemed rather challenging to me and I suggested whatever comprehensible I could find to refer to.

Comment: We would simply say "This joke was told in three versions." or less likely "This joke was heard in three versions" or even less likely "This joke was heard told in three versions".  If we wish to repeat an allegation or claim which we ourselves have not substantiated: "This joke is said to have been told in three versions".

Answer (score 0):

> I've heard this story be told in three versions.

is what you want to say.

I think what is going on here is that *to hear* is a verb of perception, and because of that the *to* of the infinitive *to be* is not specified.

Similar to:

> I saw him walk across the pond.
>
> I felt her touch me.
>
> I perceived him be threatening to me.

Comment: "I heard this story be told in three versions." That's not grammatical. The told should be the bare active infinitve